# To do foreign key or not to do OR Best practice in building relation through models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a small project of mine and can't decide how to join my models together. In my example:

**Artist** => has many **Album** => has many **Track**

Seems easy enough.

The problems starts when i'm trying to query **Artist** from **Track**. Do i need to `track.joins(:album)` every time or `Artist has_many :tracks, through: :albums` which is a same thing or is it better to add **Artist** foreign_key to **Track** model table and write some method to assign **Artist** to **Track** every time **Track** is added to **Album** or is it a bad practice?

I'm in need of advice storage and performance wise.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Surely you can just use the [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) ActiveRecord association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance & Storage should not be a major concern here -- those problems arise with requests; not storage capacity

You'll have the same problem with 1 million requests if you have 4 models as you would if you have 400 models

---

**[has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)**

What you're describing sounds like you'd benefit from a [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) ActiveRecord association, like this:

```
#app/models/artist.rb
Class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :albums, :class_name => 'Album'
    has_many :tracks, :class_Name => 'Track', :through => :albums
end
```

To make this work, you'll have to have two foreign keys in your track database:

```
tracks table
id | artist_id | album_id | other | columns | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to perform this kind of query:

```
@artist.tracks  #-> will come back with all the tracks for the artist (you can group by album if you require)
```

Comment: Why would i need artist_id in tracks table if i use has_many through association? It joins albums table to tracks table by tracks_album_id field and than joins artists table by albums_artist_id field, which seems like too many joins to me. And thats why question was born

Comment: Sorry - I meant to include `album_id`

Comment: This would join the tracks to albums only; but as your artist model is joined to albums, it can be joined to tracks through the albums model

Comment: I guess my fear of multiple joins in one query is gone now as nobody seems fear it) Thanks for you time

Comment: lol multiple joins is the least of your worries! What I just showed is convention -- all the processing power can handle this kind of stuff now; it's scalability & extensibility which you need to take care of :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do this:

**artist.rb**:

```
has_many :albums
```

**album.rb**:

```
belongs_to :artist
has_many :tracks
```

**track.rb**:

```
belongs_to :album
```

And when you called from controller, for example:

```
@track = Track.find(params[:id])
@album_name = @track.album.name # or better @track.album.try(:name)
@artist_name = @track.album.artist.name # or better @track.album.try(:artist).try(:name)
```

You don't have to manual join in one each one again.

Comment: But sql will use 3 tables and that's what worries me